# My code-signed DMG is rejected by GateKeeper

Tags: macos, codesign, dmg

I am trying to distribute an application (itself code-signed) inside a code-signed DMG volume, signed by a self-signed code certificate (generated using the Keychain Certificate Assistant).

I’m on macOS Mojave and I am creating the DMG using the following procedure:

1. Create a new empty folder `testsrc`
2. Copy code-signed app bundle into the new folder
3. Run

   ```
   hdiutil create -volname test -srcfolder testsrc -ov -format UDBZ test.dmg
   ```
4. Code-sign the DMG:

   ```
   codesign -s keyid test.dmg
   ```

This succeeds (no error message, return code 0). Furthermore, trying to execute `codesign` again leads to the message “test.dmg: is already signed”. I can verify the signature:

```
codesign -vvvv -d test.dmg
```

```
Executable=/path/to/test.dmg
Identifier=test
Format=disk image
CodeDirectory v=20100 size=291 flags=0x0(none) hashes=1+6 location=embedded
Hash type=sha256 size=32
CandidateCDHash sha256=73…
Hash choices=sha256
Page size=none
CDHash=73… (same as above)
Signature size=1760
Authority=keyid
Signed Time=12 Dec 2018 at 18:26:31
Info.plist=not bound
TeamIdentifier=not set
Sealed Resources=none
Internal requirements count=1 size=96
```

However, when I try to open the quarantined (downloaded from localhost) DMG, I get the usual Gatekeeper error message:

[image: Gatekeeper: "“test.dmg” can’t be opened because it is from an unidentified developer"]

Furthermore, `spctl -v -a -t open --context context:primary-signature test.dmg` tells me: “test.dmg: rejected”.

Is this purely because my certificate is self-signed rather than being an Apple Developer ID Application certificate? Is there a way around it?

---

I’ve seen the answers in [How to add codesigning to dmg file in mac](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23824815/1968) but they assume that the above procedure should work.

Comment: (For what it’s worth, the app bundle iteself seems to correctly validate, both via `codesign --verify` and `spctl -v -a -t exec`.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26834676/233944

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this purely because my certificate is self-signed rather than being an Apple Developer ID Application certificate?

In a nutshell: yes.

After using the key from an Apple signed developer certificate, the error went away and the application now passes validation by Gatekeeper.

Comment: It’s quite an unsatisfactory answer but I hope it helps people finding this question via googling. At the time when I was asking this, it was essentially impossible to find any information on the subject.

Comment: It's still difficult to find definitive information...  Apple's documentation only covers very specific use cases that never seem to match up with mine.  I signed with a Comodo certificate and it *appears* to work fine locally.  However, if I move the DMG to our website and download from there, *then* it fails.  I'll try an Apple cert next...

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch From macOS Catalina onwards code signing is no longer sufficient, [you need to get each app notarised](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09032019a).

Comment: Ah, good to know.  I was under the mistaken belief notarization was only for App Store.  Interestingly when I try to make my Developer ID cert the option is grayed out and it tells me to contact my Team Admin.  I am an admin...  Will see if one of the other admins can do it.